# Accessing shared network folders on a workstation via remote ssh in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

The situation is like this. I have a university workstation with access to a network-shared folder. I have to put my credentials to access the data in those folders. I mapped those folders to the workstation using the command `net use` in the `CMD`. Also, I have access to connect to this workstation via ssh and I can connect to it and access the local files on the workstation.

The problem is when I connect via ssh, I can not find the mapped network location. I tried to run `net use` remotely and it found the mapped location but the status is `Unavailable`.

The workstation is a Windows machine, and I use a mac laptop. What is a possible solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a remote session of Visual Studio Code runs in a different session that does not have the same network share mounts as the user account would have when logged in locally.  This may be a result of the OpenSSH `sshd` process running as the SYSTEM user.

## Mount shared drive manually in VS Code

I solved this issue by manually (re-)mounting the network share within the remote VS code session (powershell or cmd terminals would work):

```
net use Z: "\\server\sharename"
```

The downside to this method is that VS Code must first open an accessible project folder before allowing a terminal window to be opened.  The command could be run in an independent SSH connection prior to opening VS Code.

Another drawback is that this command must be run each time the remote machine is rebooted.

## Mount shared drive upon SSH connection

To automatically mount shared drive(s) on SSH connection (which VS Code uses to connect to the remote machine), add the following option to the `.ssh/config` file:

```
RemoteCommand powershell -NoExit -Command "& {net use z: /delete; net use z: '\\server\sharename'}"
```

This injects commands to unmount/remount the share drive right when the powershell terminal starts.

The VS Code Remote SSH extension user settings must also be modified to enable the RemoteCommand option[<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4474):

```
"remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": true,
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrtumnus for your answer. I tried using `net use` but the desired network location's statue is `Unavailable`. Do you know a work around for this case?

Comment: @Ahmed Interestingly enough, I also see the share listed as "Unavailable".  Despite this, the share is still mounted and accessible within VS Code.  Did you see if the drive is accessible?